# Unsolvable gaussian elimination(when 3rd row is a sum of the 2 preceeding rows) Why does this not work?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am looking at linear algebra presently and am looking at elimination. Hoping to expand my understanding.

Is there an explanation to the reason why the system becomes unsolvable when equation 1 and 2 add up to make equation 3?

Eg.

$3x-1y+2z = 6$

$x +2y-z  = 4$

$4x+1y+1z = 10$

$$\begin{bmatrix}
3 & -1 & 2 \\\\
1 & 2 & -1 \\\\
4 & 1 & 1 \\\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
6 \\\\
4 \\\\
10\\\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you only really have two equations, because the third one is a linear combination of the first two. And if you only have two equations of three variables then there isn’t a unique solution

Comment: A good explanation is @6.30 on this video https://youtube.com/watch?v=CrV1xCWdY-g